# Problema al hacer Web Scraping a página que no tiene el mismo contenido HTML en el código fuente

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, scraping, beautifulsoup

Estoy practicando Web Scraping con `requests` (para hacer la petición) y `BeautifulSoup` para hacer el parseo, mis pruebas funcionaban perfectamente hasta que me encontré con una página web que se podría decir "Con una estructura rara". A continuación les muestro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Página a la que quiero hacer Scraping](https://larepublica.pe/economia/)

Quiero hacer web Scraping a esta web, descargando cada árticulo de noticias que están dentro de una etiqueta `<section>` que vendría a ser el contenedor total.

**NOTA** : Realmente la pagina tiene dos elementos `<section>`, en toda mi explicación sólo me estoy refiriendo al de los artículos como lo señala la imagen.

Al momento de hacer el Scraping, me doy cuenta de que no devuelve nada. Es en ese momento que analizo el código fuente HTML de la página y me encuentro con que la etiqueta `<section>` (que contenía esos artículos) no existía, esa etiqueta se generaba con código JavaScript, y es por eso que mi parseador no podía encontrar la información que quería. **Con esto me di cuenta que el código fuente de una página no es necesariamente igual que el que se muestra cuando le doy `Inspeccionar` en la sección Elements de la DevTools.**

Entonces mi consulta es la siguiente:
¿Hay alguna forma de poder hacer Scraping a esa página? o ¿ya fue?.

Después de toda la explicación dejo mi código por si quieren probarlo.

[Enlace código Python de Web Scraping usando BeatifulSoup](https://github.com/KodingT/Scraping_LaRepublica/blob/main/Scraping_LaRepublica.py)

Comment: Las páginas en las que puedes hacer `scrolldown` suelen mostrarte más información que mediante `beautifulsoup` no podrás obtener, para estos casos es recomendable utilizar [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Dependiendo que browser utilizas deberás descargar el driver indicado, chrome(chromedriver) o firefox(geckodriver)